# How To Convert HttpURLConnection to Volley

Tags: java, android

I have google a lot but i can find solution about my issue my old code for call web service from my activity i have pass two parameter one is link means URL and second is parameters is for data i have to send to server.
problem is i have to use volley in place of following code

`call retrieveStream("www.xyz.com/abc.php","data=dfsds");`

```
public static String retrieveStream(String link, String parameters) {
    try {
        link = link.replace(" ", "%20");

        URL url = new URL(link);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();

        String line = "";
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        // Response from server after login process will be stored in
        // response variable.
        String response = sb.toString();
        // You can perform UI operations here
        isr.close();
        reader.close();
        return response;

    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}`
```

I have implement in volley

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            JSONUtils.WEB_SERVICE + "pausetest.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // mPostCommentResponse.requestCompleted();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // mPostCommentResponse.requestEndedWithError(error);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("allanswer", alldata);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);`
```

Comment: i have to convert my code to volley request for android

Comment: i am getting error in volley "414: Request too long"

Comment: thanks a lot to all i got solution response always returns from cache memory in volley

Answer (score 0):

FYI.  This is assuming that your using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, as to a multi-part-form.  I believe the Volley document/videos state somewhere that it is not meant for large data transfers.

I usually make a separate class for my various distinct Volley call, especially for restful processing or reuse as follows:

```
package com.your.package;

public class MyVolleyRequest1 {


public void myUniqueVolleyRequest(final String _parameter1, final String _parameter2) {

    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        apiNetworkUnAvailableMsg("No network for this function.");
        return;
    }

    RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();

    StringRetroFIXRequest myReq = new StringRetroFIXRequest(Method.POST,
            getMyContext().getString(R.string.http_url),
            createMyReqSuccessListener(),
            createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


            params.put("parameter 1", _parameter1);
            params.put("parameter 2", _parameter2);
            return params;
        }

        ;
    };
    queue.add(myReq);

}


private Response.Listener<String> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            setResponseSuccess(response);
        }
    };
}


private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            setResponseSuccess(error.toString());
        }
    };
}


private void setResponseSuccess(String result) {

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventBusResultsClassResponseDone(result));

}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getMyContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


private void apiNetworkUnAvailableMsg(String _purpose) {
    String mReturn = "Internet connection unavailable. Try " + _purpose + " at a later time.";
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new VolleyReturnEvent(mReturn));
}
}
```

I also use EventBus, so that I can loosely couple the return value(s), especially, if I decide I want to put those results into a model (pojo), like for using MVC/MVP type processing or say specialized processing of json, etc.

Optionally I also like to use OKHttp in combination Volley, here are the dependencies for gradle in Android Studio.

```
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
```

If you are just going to do restful processing Retrofit is a cool library.

Implementing in your Activity or Fragment you then define the above class and instantiate with the parameters, if needed.  My example has 2 parameters.  Then you implement EventBus, define the eventbus class, and include the return events via EventBus in your app, including the generic VolleyError which is returned as a separate event for error processing.

Here's a gist of what I'd put in my activity to call and then get responses from Volley/OKHttp.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    EventBus.getDefault().register(this); 

    requestMyVolleyResponse1();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onPause();

}


private void requestMyVolleyResponse1() {
    MyVolleyRequest1 mVolleyRequest1 = new MyVolleyRequest1();




    mVolleyRequest1.MyVolleyRequest1("Parameter 1 value","Parameter 2 value");
}


public void onEventMainThread(MyVolleyRequest1Done event) {
    // Your successful response processing.
}


public void onEventMainThread(VolleyReturnEvent event) {
   // Your Error Processing
    ;
}
```

The EventBus return classes that you have to define (VolleyReturnEvent, MyVolleyRequest1Done) are really simple, i.e.

public class VolleyReturnEvent {
    public final String message;

```
public VolleyReturnEvent(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}